# Android GUI control names

Tags: android, android-source

I am still learning android and I have some controls which I dont know what its called:

The first one is this:

[image]

the copy and paste "holder" in the default app of samsung tab messaging.

2nd is the:

[image]

the holder of "table of contents", "bookmarks", etc.

What do we call these controls?

Comment: what do you mean by holder? the element containing "select word" and "select all"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called QuickActions, and were initially implemented in the Twitter for Android app, developed by Google. Here's an excellent Google blog article with these patterns: [Twitter for Android: A closer look at Android’s evolving UI patterns](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html). The [QuickContactBadge](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/QuickContactBadge.html) is one such element that was added in API Level 5.

Comment: WOW! thank you very very much! i've been looking for these for the whole day :)